# Weird plot for the discrete Fourier transform of a normal distribution compared to Matlab

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

In mathematica, why does

`Print[ListPlot[Fourier[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {100000}]],PlotRange -> All]];`

return an empty plot, sometimes with a random dot, while in matlab,

```
plot(fft(randn([1 100000])))
```

returns

[image]

I've checked the the normal distributions created seem identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `Print[ ]` and you should pass into `ListPlot` a list of *pairs* of points coordinates, not a list of complex numbers:

```
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Fourier[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {100000}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Or like this:

```
ListPlot[Fourier[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {100000}]] /. a_Complex -> {Re[a], Im[a]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Note that FFT is defined in a different manner in MATLAB and in WM (see help for the corresponding functions). In WM the FFT has $1/\sqrt{n}$ multiplier, while no multiplier is used in MATLAB. You can change the definition of the FFT using `FourierParameters` option:

```
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Fourier[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {100000}], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

Now it is consistent with MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks. But why are the amplitudes still different? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXugc.jpg

Comment: I'll update the answer